# Yii. Condition on Many_Many relations

Tags: php, search, yii, many-to-many, conditional-statements

I have simple structure:
Users have posts, posts have tags.

How can I get all tags, which assigned with posts of given user?

I tried do it this way:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->with = array('posts');

$criteria->addSearchCondition('posts.user_id', $this->id);
//or this (by the way, what's the difference?):
//$criteria->compare('posts.user_id', $this->id);

$tags = Tag::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But it has problems.. This condition give me tags, which assigned ONLY with posts of this user. But I need to get tags, which assigned at least with one post of this user.

In other words, if it is tag, which is assigned with two posts: post1 and post2 (post1.user_id=1 post2.user_id=2), but my user has id=1, then this tag wouldn't be in result. But I want get this tag, because it is assigned with post1 (post1.user_ud=1), and I don't care about other posts/users.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, You are looking for a way to get all tags a user ever used.
The easiest way to set up a MANY_to_MANY rel is in the model relations :

in your User model:

```
function relations()
{
    return array(
        'tags' => array(
            self::MANY_MANY,
            'Tag',
            'posts(user_id, tag_id)'
        ),
    );
}
```

and then with your model you would just be able to request them :

```
//gives you all the tags for user with PK 1
$usertags = User::model()->findByPK(1)->tags;
```

Reference : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

EDIT : Based on the comments I edit my post with more examples on Active Record

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with='tags'; 
$criteria->select='tag_name'; 
$criteria->condition='user=:userID';
$criteria->params=array(':userID'=>10);
$usertags =User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. Anyway, I would like to sort/filter/limit results. Will I be able to do it your way? If Yes, how?

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not what I mean.. 
You wrote:
...'posts(user_id, tag_id)'...
But post and tags isn't assigned directly. It is relation MANY_MANY too (post can have many tags, and it doesn't has field 'tag_id').

Comment: you can do this with the trough paramerer : google ftw : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through

Comment: "through can be used with HAS_ONE, BELONGS_TO and HAS_MANY relations", but as I said, I have MANY_MANY relation. It is not what I need..

Comment: yes that's true, although you can make models for your glue tables wich you then can relate with has_many, and from there on you can go trough User::model()->posts->tags, it's not ideal but it works